# How to make sure that I got the solution to a problem correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question

I'm a physicst autodidact and I've always relied on solution manuals up till now. There are however a lot of great books with no solution manuals that I'd like to study. What should I do? How do I make sure that my solutions are correct and I've not misunderstood something from the theory?

Comment: Sanity checks can go a long way. Check dimensional analysis. Check whether conservation laws are followed and universal constants are still themselves. Input plausible test values and see if you get physically plausible results. Check for undefined regions in your domains - have you divided by a variable with a domain that includes 0? If your solution is a function, try graphing it.

Comment: @gs I think your comment is an answer of the question. Would you like to convert it to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a question regarding a derivation (atleast those of Classical Mechanics), dimensional analysis does go a long way.

Another way is the use of logic as much as possible. Something I learnt from my teacher was about getting the "feel" of the answer.

Say for F = m/a

I would think, *does a heavier object require more force to move?* The answer is a Yes, so the direct proportionality checks out.
Then the equation also indicates mass is inversely proportional to acceleration. *Do heavier objects move slower with the same force?* The answer would again be yes.
So our equation checks out in both ways.

This is a simple example, but using it in certain cases can help you grasp something more easily or help you cross-verify your answer. It doesn't hold for the more non-intuitive cases. It might seem small/simple/easy but can lend you that helping hand when you desperately need it.